# Run Java in Online Workspace Enviornment?

Tags: java

I am attempting to work collaboratively online with a partner to run java (https://c9.io/). I need the ability to collaborate in Java with a partner. Unfortunately, every time I try to run java I get the error "Could not find or load main class [name]". I imported my folder I would be working in with all the class files. So my question is, is there a way that I could run java online without getting the class error? Am I doing something wrong?

My code is very basic java (and I'm a beginner so don't make the answer too complicated please).

```
public class greeting {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       System.out.println("Hello World!")
    }

}
```

That is the code I am trying to run (above).

Comment: This isn't android code, it is basic java. Removing android tag.

Comment: please provide the error... BTW your class name is in lowercase...

Answer (score 1):

You are likely calling your program like so

```
java name
```

you need to call your program

```
java greeting name
```

The first typed word is the program "java", the second depends on the command, but for java, one needs to include the *classname* which seems to be greeting in your example.

The others are arguments passed into the class's main method.

Answer (score 0):

Class must be in caps, like `public Class Greeting`

We follow a camel casing in java

Comment: No, the must not be in caps, but I fully agree it's a nicer world when they are in caps.

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning the project and then building it, if that doesn't already happen after you clean it.